# I am not able to retrieve data that is uploaded to firebase by a flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this fetch function for javascript. it can only retrieve data that are added manually on the firebase console, but those documents that are uploaded from the application is not being retrieved by the HTML website.

My JavaScript code:

```js
async function fetchData() {
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "processed");
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);

  if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
    for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
      const uid = doc.id;
      console.log("Processing UID:", uid);

      const reportsCollectionRef = collection(db, "processed", uid, "reports");
      const reportsSnapshot = await getDocs(reportsCollectionRef);

      console.log(
        "Number of reports for UID",
        uid,
        ":",
        reportsSnapshot.size
      );

      if (!reportsSnapshot.empty) {
        reportsSnapshot.forEach((reportDoc) => {
          const data = reportDoc.data();
          console.log("Retrieved Data:", data);

          const newLocation = {
            id: counter++,
            date: data.currentDate,
            latitude: data.latitude,
            longitude: data.longitude,
            elevation: data.changeInYAxis.toFixed(4),
          };

          locations.push(newLocation);
        });
      } else {
        console.log("No reports for UID", uid);
      }
    }
    // Initialize map and markers here, after the data is loaded
    initializeMap();

    // Update the table with the new data
    updateTable();
  }
}
```

My flutter code:

```dart
Future<void> uploadProcessedToFirebase() async {
  try {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    User? user = userCredential.user;
    String uid = user!.uid;

    if (user != null) {
      FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      String collectionId = DateTime.now().toUtc().toString();
      DocumentReference disturbanceReport = firestore.collection("processed").doc(uid).collection("reports").doc(collectionId);

      // Get data using existing functions
      String currentTime = getCurrentTime();
      String currentDate = getCurrentDate();

      // Retrieve latitude and longitude separately
      double latitude = initialCameraPosition?.latitude ?? 0.0;
      double longitude = initialCameraPosition?.longitude ?? 0.0;

      // Add the data to Firestore
      await disturbanceReport.set({
        'latitude': latitude,
        'longitude': longitude,
        'currentTime': currentTime,
        'currentDate': currentDate,
        'changeInYAxis' : changeInYValue,
      });

      // Display success toast
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Upload successful",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        textColor: Colors.white,
      );

      print('Data added to Firestore successfully');
    } else {
      print('Anonymous login failed');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Display error toast
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Error uploading data",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
    );

    print('Error adding data to Firestore: $e');
  }
```

The function is intended to retrieve all documents in the collection with a unique UID. Now it can only retrieve those that are added  manually using the console, while those data that are uploaded by the application is not being retrieved. It also doesn't show in console log.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to  share the application (flutter) code.

Comment: At first glance the Flutter and JavaScript code seem to line up, so I'd start by looking elsewhere for the problem? For example: are the documents in the `reports` showing in the Firebase console? If not, they're never making it off the Flutter app - so you'll know the problem is (likely a connectivity issue) there.

Comment: it just happened  when i  deleted a collection. after that I started to upload data from the app, the document and fields are present in the firebase console but when I start fetching using the web app, it does not show the  existing documents in the table in the  web app. If I create a new document manually, it is showing in the  table

Comment: does reaching the flutter read quota in  firestore affects the fetch function?